# Component Not Updating After State Changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I am trying to dispatch an action that modifies the "matrix" array in the state,the array is getting modified,but the component is updated only if I hardcode the returned array inside the MUp() function.

The Reducer:

```
export const initialState = {
    board: {
    matrix: [
         [4, 2, 0, 0],
         [4, 2, 4, 0],
         [4, 0, 16, 2],
         [4, 2, 32, 0],
         ],
   },
};
export const board = (state = initialState.board, action) => {
    if (action.type == MOVE_UP) {
       return {
            ...state,
            matrix: MUp(state),
       };
    } 
    return state;
};
const MUp = (state) => {
    let mat = state.matrix;
    const size = state.gridSize;
    var ok;
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        ok = 1;
        while (ok) {
          ok = 0;
          for (var i = size - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (mat[i][j] != 0) {
              if (mat[i + 1][j] == mat[i][j]) {
                mat[i][j] = 0;
                mat[i + 1][j] = 2 * mat[i + 1][j];
                ok = 1;
              } else {
                if (mat[i + 1][j] == 0) {
                  mat[i + 1][j] = mat[i][j];
                  mat[i][j] = 0;
                  ok = 1;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      console.log("up");
      return mat;
};
```

The Action:

```
export const moveUp = () => {
  return {
    type: MOVE_UP,
  };
};
```

And The Function Where I Dispatch The Action:

```
export const Moves = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") dispatch(moveUp());
  });
  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer appears to be mutating the existing array.  `let mat = state.matrix` just creates another reference to the *same* array in memory, and `mat[i][j] =` also mutates the nested array.

A critical rule of immutable updates is that you *must* copy *every* level of nesting that you need to update.  So, you'd need to make a copy of `state.matrix` and `state.matrix[i]`.

Note that you should really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux).  Not only does it detect accidental mutations like this, it would actually let you write this same "mutating" logic, but RTK automatically turns those "mutations" into a safe and correct immutable update internally using Immer:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#immutable-updates-with-immer